# $wpdb won't insert NULL into table column

Tags: database, wpdb

When i try something like this

```
    $status = NULL;

    $wpdb->update(
            'table',
            array( 
                'status' => $status,
            ), 
            array( 'id' => 1 ) 
    );
```

In the 'status' column now i have an empty string `''`, it simply won't set it to NULL.

The column can be NULL of course. I've also tested $wpdb->query and $wpdb->prepare and the results are the same. Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Update:

Since WordPress 4.4. this is now supported by the `insert`, `update`, `replace` and `delete` methods of `wpdb` and the ticket [#15158](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15158) has been closed as *fixed*.

Thanks to @dmsnell for [commenting](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143405/wpdb-wont-insert-null-into-table-column/143418?noredirect=1#comment344974_143418) about that update.

On the other hand, the `null` support in `wpdb::prepare()` is currently closed as  *wontfix* in ticket [#12819](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12819).

*Previous answer:*

### `NULL` not supported:

It looks like you will have to write your own custom SQL to update the value with `NULL`.

Currently `NULL` is not supported by `$wpdb->prepare()`, that takes the input through the [vsprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) formatting function.

Check out these open Trac tickets:

- [wpdb::prepare support for null](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12819)
- [wpdb insert & update with null values](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15158)

These tickets are about 4 years old, so I wouldn't hold my breath until this gets supported by the core ;-)

You should take a look at the source as @s_ha_dum suggested.

### A possible workaround:

If you're adventurous you can try the following with the `query` filter:

```
    // Add a filter to replace the 'NULL' string with NULL
    add_filter( 'query', 'wpse_143405_query' );

    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->update(
        'table',
        array( 
            'status' => 'NULL',
        ), 
        array( 'id' => 1 ) 
    );

    // Remove the filter again:
    remove_filter( 'query', 'wpse_143405_query' );
```

where

```
/**
 * Replace the 'NULL' string with NULL
 * 
 * @param  string $query
 * @return string $query
 */

function wpse_143405_query( $query )
{
    return str_ireplace( "'NULL'", "NULL", $query ); 
}
```

You might want to use a more unique string than `'NULL'` to replace, perhaps `'###NULL###'` instead.

Comment: support for setting `NULL` was added in [r34737](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/34737), so there is no longer any need for a workaround

Answer (score 3):

`wpdb->update` defaults to a string for all data types.

> > **format**
> >         (array|string) (optional) An array of formats to be mapped to each of the value in $data. If string, that format will be used for
> >     all of
> >     the values in $data. *If omitted, all values in $data will be treated
> >     as strings* unless otherwise specified in `wpdb::$field_types`.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows

You can specify a format but the allowable specifiers are:

> > **Possible format values**: %s as string; %d as integer (whole number) and
> >     %f as float. (See below for more information.) If omitted, all values
> >     in $where will be treated as strings.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows

You can [read through the source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1733) and work out the process.

If you hack the `wpdb->prepare` method (on a dev server that gets wiped clean periodically :) ) to dump the SQL before just before the return, you will see that the replacement happens before `wpdb->prepare`:

```
string(48) "UPDATE `table` SET `status` = %s WHERE `id` = %s"
```

Though, as suggested by @birgire, it may well be a limit to `prepare` that prompted that replacement.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to further explain how to do this in WP 4.4 and beyond. You need to set both the data and format element that you wish to be null to a PHP 'null' value.

The example in ticket [#15158](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15158) is as follows:

```
$wpdb->update($ttable, 
              [
                'user_id' => NULL,
                'status' => 'available',
                'update_time' => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
              ], [
                'therapist_id' => $therapist_id,
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'start_time' => $ub['start_time']
              ], [
                 NULL,
                 '%s',
                 '%s'
              ], [
                 '%d',
                 '%d',
                 '%s'
            ]);
```