# wpdb insert and boolean fields

Tags: mysql, wpdb

I'm preparing an insert query like this:

```
$wpdb->insert('table', $data, $format);
```

data array will be:

```
$data = array_push($data, 'resp' => true)
```

problem is, what $format shall i use for a boolean field?

```
$format = array_push($format, '%%')
```

in the codex i found only %s (for strings) %d (for integers) and %f (for floats)...but what about booleans?

Comment: Check out this [question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143405/wpdb-wont-insert-null-into-table-column) and the answers, it's related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BOOL` or `BOOLEAN` are as far as MYSQL is concerned just replacements/synonyms for `TINYINT(1)`, tiny integer, so using `%d` for integers is the correct way to do it.

*Some additional information:*

- [Codex: Class Reference - wpdb - Placeholders](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Placeholders)
- [MySQL: Numeric Type Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html)
- [MySQL: Boolean Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/boolean-literals.html)
- [MySQL: Integer Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: and what about BIT fields? they should be inserted as `b'1'`

Comment: @Mariano I don't know about the `BIT` type, I never used it in a wordpress/wpdb context, so can't help you there, but it's interesting, so you might want to ask another question.